# synchronising the Time without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web app that uses the Time of the computer I found how I can get the  hours and the minutes and I succeeded to update them to the UI but the minute field is not synchronised with the time of the computer I have to reload the page to see it updated with the new value, I don't know how to solve this problem I feel like it's a stupid question but really I'm struggling with it, it's my first app with JavaScript so forgive me :p

I tried the `setInterval` but it didn't work too any help please 
here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="headTime" >Time: <span class="Time"> 03:19</span></div>
```

**Js**

```
    var hours=d.getHours();
    var minutes=d.getMinutes();

    var Time=" 03:19";

    var newTime=Time.replace("03",hours);
    var newTime=newTime.replace("19",minutes);

    setInterval(function(){
  document.querySelector(".Time").innerHTML=newTime;
    },1000);
```

any better title for the question?
I feel it's not accurate

Comment: setInterval to 10 milliseconds?

Comment: If you're only showing hours and minutes, there's no reason to run the function every second. Just run it every minute.

Comment: You have the right idea; but you are only calculating the `newtime` string once, and then setting the same value in the `setInterval` function. You need the whole calculation of `newTime` to be in the `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the date each time in callback passed to `setInterval`. I have added seconds also for test purpose.

You donot need to get the test of `span` and use `replace()` and then show. You could directly use Template Strings

```
`${hours}:${minutes}`
```

Tip for you is declare the element `.Time` in global scope and don't call `querySelector` every second

```js
const span = document.querySelector(".Time");

setInterval(function(){
    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let mins = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    span.innerHTML= `${hours}:${mins}:${seconds}`;
},1000);
```

```html
<div class="headTime" >Time: <span class="Time"> 03:19</span></div>
```

**Note**:If you are only showing the minutes no seconds you shouldn't call the function every second